# Cannot understand how it works?

Tags: c++, pointers

```
vector <int> nums = {1, 1, 3, 3, 6, 10, 12, 12};
auto element = unique(nums.begin(), nums.end());
auto begin = nums.begin();
int result = element - begin;
cout << *element << endl; //10
cout << *begin << endl; //1
cout << el << endl; //5 unique numbers in the vector
cout << &element << endl;//0x7fffb577ed88
cout << &begin << endl;  //0x7fffb577ed90
```

How do we get 5? If address of the unique(nums.begin(), nums.end()) is 0x7ffebffb288 and address of nums.begin() = 0x7ffebffb2850?

It must be 8, mustn't it?

Comment: you have three duplicates (1, 3, and 12). 8 - 3 = 5. that's what the `unique` iteration does

Comment: Is unique supposed to be returning how many unique elements are in the vector? That would be 5, then.

Comment: `unique()` reorganises the range so duplicates are at the end, and returns an iterator that references the first duplicate.   There are five unique values, so the returned iterator must be five past `nums.begin()`.

Comment: In addition to the comments and answer posted here, I would only add that I don't think attempting to use memory addresses is a particularly meaningful way to reason about this.

Comment: @Subuday I'm sure you mistyped the addresses. (They have a different number of digits.) Can you provide the code you used to get them?

Comment: The return value of `std::unique()` is an iterator. The code is subtracting the `begin` iterator from that returned iterator to get the distance between them. That distance is just an integer, not a pointer or iterator, so dereferencing that value is not a valid operation and [does not compile](https://www.ideone.com/RkugjC). `cout << *element` should be just `cout << element`

Comment: @ HolyBlackCat `std::unique()` returns an iterator to the element that follows the last element not removed. I still can't understand why the range between first and this iterator includes all the elements in the sequence that were not considered duplicates. How does it work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::unique` does this:

> Eliminates all but the first element from every consecutive group of equivalent elements from the range [first, last) and returns a past-the-end iterator for the new logical end of the range.

In other words, the value gotten by subtracting `nums.begin()` from the return value of `unique(nums.begin(), nums.end())` is the length of the list after it has performed its operation of removing consecutive duplicates. Without any consecutive duplicates in your vector, we have: 1, 3, 6, 10, 12.

That's 5 elements.

Comment: "*the return value is the length of the list after it has performed its operation*" - more accurately, the return value of `std::unique()` is an iterator, and the code is then subtracting the `begin` iterator from that returned iterator to get the distance between them, which is 5 elements.

Comment: @RemyLebeau You're right. Updated my post to avoid giving the (wrong) impression that `std::unique` on its own returns the length of the unique list.